# Where do you put this kind of controller code in an angular app?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

The following code is needed in 2 different controllers (at the moment, maybe more controllers later).  The code works around a problem I've found in ng-grid and allows the delayed selection of a row (once the data has been loaded).

```
    // Watch for the ngGridEventData signal and select indexToSelect from the grid in question.
    // eventCount parameter is a hack to hide a bug where we get ngGridEventData spam that will cause the grid to deselect the row we just selected 
    function selectOnGridReady(gridOptions, indexToSelect, eventCount) {
        // Capture the grid id for the grid we want, and only react to that grid being updated.
        var ngGridId = gridOptions.ngGrid.gridId;
        var unWatchEvent = $scope.$on('ngGridEventData', function(evt, gridId) {
            if(ngGridId === gridId) {
                //gridEvents.push({evt: evt, gridId:gridId});
                var grid = gridOptions.ngGrid;

                gridOptions.selectItem(indexToSelect, true);
                grid.$viewport.scrollTop(grid.rowMap[0] * grid.config.rowHeight);

                if($scope[gridOptions.data] && $scope[gridOptions.data].length) {
                    eventCount -= 1;
                    if(eventCount <= 0) {
                        unWatchEvent(); // Our selection has been made, we no longer need to watch this grid
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem I have is where do I put this common code?  It's obviously UI code, so it doesn't seem like it belongs in a service, but there is no classical inheritance scheme (that I have been able to  discover) that would allow me to put it in a "base class"

Ideally, this would be part of ng-grid, and wouldn't involve such a nasty hack, but ng-grid 2.0 is closed to features and ng-grid 3.0 is who knows how far out into the future.

A further wrinkle is the $scope that I guess I would have to inject into this code if I pull it from the current controller.

Does this really belong in a service?

Comment: You could try using a mixin. http://digital-drive.com/?p=188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just put this in a service and pass $scope into it but you do have other options. You may want to take a look at this presentation as it covers different ways of organizing your code: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1OgABsN24ZWN6Ugng-O8SjF7t0e3liQ9UN7hKdrCr0K8/present?pli=1&ueb=true#slide=id.p

**Mixins**

You could put it in its own object and mix it into any controllers using angular.extend();

```
var ngGridUtils = {
    selectOnGridReady: function(gridOptions, indexToSelect, eventCount) {
        ...
    }
};

var myCtrl = function() {...};
angular.extend(myCtrl, ngGridUtils);
```

**Inheritance**

If you use the 'controller as' syntax for your controllers then you can treat them like classes and just use javascript inheritance.

```
var BaseCtrl = function() {
    ...
}

BaseCtrl.prototype.selectOnGridReady = function(gridOptions, indexToSelect, eventCount) {
    ...
};

var MyCtrl = function() {
    BaseCtrl.call(this);
};

MyCtrl.prototype = Object.create(BaseCtrl.prototype);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl"></div>
```

Comment: 3 ways to look into. Thank you very much.  I have some other unanswered questions if you feel up to the challenge :-)